# Updating an item while iterating over a result set in Python/psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a list of entities in a database which I retrieve and iterate over them like this:

```
  import psycopg2

  cur.execute("select * from items")
  rows = cur.fetchall()
  for x in rows:
    # some stuff
```

I want to be able to update some of the fields on an entity inside the loop.

```
  for x in rows:
    # some stuff
    if some_condition:
      curr.execute("update items set....
```

Is it possible to do so inside the loop? If not, what's the workaround? Updating them all at once after the loop doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think the cursor will hold on to transactions so you would have to handle that in each loop.

Comment: Do it all in sql.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, mysql?

Comment: @Kuqa No, do it using SQL only not Python.